# Subspace of a polynomial ring

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory

Let $\mathbb{R}[x]$ be the ring of polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$.
Further $d \in \mathbb{Z}$ and$$ \mathbb{R}[x]_d:= p \in \mathbb{R}[x] : deg(p) \leq d $$
$$ \mathbb{R}[x]_{=d}:= p \in \mathbb{R}[x] : deg(p) = d $$ Determine the minimum subspaces of $\mathbb{R}[x]$ which include $\mathbb{R}[x]_{d}$ and $\mathbb{R}[x]_{=d}$

I have trouble to prove it formally correct. From my understanding it can't be "0", because "0" can't satisfy "$ \mathbb{R}[x]_{=d}:= p \in \mathbb{R}[x] : deg(p) = d $"

So I need something like 
$
f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^d a_ix^i
$ to produce $ \mathbb{R}[x]_{=d}$ and  $\mathbb{R}[x]_{d}$

Is that all I can do or is there a proper formal way?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can verify that $\mathbb R[x]_d$ is actually a subspace. The smallest subspace containing $\mathbb R[x]_{=d}$ is $\mathbb R[x]_d$. I won't give a full proof, but note that any polynomial of degree less than $d$ can be written as the difference of two polynomials of degree $d$. For example,
$$x=(x^2+x)-x^2$$